# React Router 4 -- handling 404 for nested routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4, nested-routes

I have the following code and I am going to handle nested route while wrong one is entered:

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/sample" exact component={Sample} />
<Route path="/sample/example/:id" exact component={Example} />
<Route path="/sample/:example" exact component={Example} />
<Route component={404}/>
</Switch>
```

If user enters `localhost:3000/something-wrong`, it will show 404 page correctly. However, when he enters `localhost:3000/sample/something-wrong`, nothing is rendered!
How should I handle this issue in a manner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost:3000/sample/something-wrong` is handled by `path="/sample/:example"`

`localhost:3000/sample/example/something-wrong` would be handled by `path="/sample/example/:id"`

as you are using wild-cards, there's really nothing you can do except enable the `Example` component to render an appropriate message, or maybe redirect to a dedicated 404 screen.